# How to execute only after midnight calendar on android ?

Tags: android, calendar

recently ,if current time is set time zone, execute A start.

```
String start_time = "23:00";
String End_time = "04:00";

String[] str_Stime = start_time.split(":");
String[] str_Etime = End_time.split(":");

//start_time array
Calendar calStime = Calendar.getInstance();
calStime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(str_Stime[0]));
calStime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(str_Stime[1]));

//End_time array 
Calendar calEtime = Calendar.getInstance();
calEtime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //04:00 is after midnight (tomorrow time);
calEtime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(str_Etime[0]));
calEtime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(str_Etime[1]));

//Current time
Calendar calCurrent = Calendar.getInstance();

//check time
if (calCurrent.getTimeInMillis() >= calStime.getTimeInMillis() & calCurrent.getTimeInMillis() <= calEtime.getTimeInMillis()) {
    //A start
} else {
    // current time is not set time zone.
}
```

but this source 1 problem. `calEtime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

`add(Calendar.DATE,1)` only execute `start_time` or `End_time` is after midnight.

because if

```
start_time = "09:00" //I want set 2017-02-24 09:00
end_time = "11:00"   //I want set 2017-02-24 11:00

.  
.
//End_time
Calendar calEtime = Calendar.getInstance();
calEtime.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //set tomorrow 2017-02-25.
```

so, I want only after midnight execute `add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`
How to execute only after midnight on android ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following line to start from next day
 calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

Full Code-

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MenuActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    pendingIntent);
```

Comment: thanks, but I don't understand why use `Calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);`   this is set date first day on this month.     I want execute only after midnight.

Comment: It will add 1 to current day i.e next day.

Comment: I know add 1 to current day. is `Calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`   your answer not work..